# Why is 'bicrement' not possible like this?

Tags: language-agnostic, increment

Why is this not possible?

```
int c = 0;
++c++;
```

Or in PHP:

```
$c = 0;
++$c++;
```

I would expect it to increment the variable c by 2, or perhaps do something weird, but instead it gives an error while compiling. I've tried to come up with a reason but got nothing really... My reasoning was this:

1. The compiler reads ++
2. It reads the variable
3. It does whatever it does to make the value of the variable increment and then get returned when executing the application
4. It encounters another ++
5. It uses the previous variable in order to return it before incrementing the value
6. This is where it gets confusing: does it use the variable c, or does it try to read the value that (++c) returned? Or, since you can only do varname++ (and not 2++), does it see (++c) as a pointer and then tries to read that memory location? Whatever it does, why would it give a compile error? Or is the error preventive, because the compiler's programmer knew it wouldn't do anything useful?

It's not really that I would want to use this, and certainly not for code that is not one-time use only, but I'm just curious.

Comment: you can't modify a returned value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the same reason you can't do:

```
c++ = 5;
```

It returns a value, which cannot be modified nor assigned to. That's not a runtime error, either - that's a compilation error. [(Like this one.)](http://codepad.org/zJKPMfOO)

Returning a reference wouldn't make sense either, because then:

```
$a = 1;
$b = $a++; // How can it be a reference if b should be 1 and a should be 2?
```

Comment: I see, clear explanation. It sounds so logic once you understand... ^^ Would accept your answer, but must wait 6 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't *necessarily* language-agnostic, although I'd be a little surprised to see a language in which it was different.

In C (and hence I assume in all non-annoying languages based on C), the operator precedence means your expression is equivalent to `++(c++)`. Based on your step-by-step, you were expecting it to be equivalent to `(++c)++`, but it isn't. Postfix `++` "binds more tightly" than prefix `++`.

Like everyone says, the expression `c++` results in a value, not a modifiable object (an expression in C that refers to an object is called an lvalue). This is necessary because the object `c` no longer holds the value that the expression evaluates to -- there is no object that `c++` could refer to.

In C++ (not to be confused with `c++`!), `++c` *is* an lvalue. It refers to the object `c`, which now has the new value.

So in C++ `(++c)++` is syntactically correct. It happens to have undefined behavior if `c` is of type `int` (at least, it did in C++03: C++11 made some things defined that used to be undefined and I'm not up to date on those changes).

So, if you imagine (or go ahead and invent) a C++-like language in which the operator precedence is what you expected, then you *could* arrange for `++c++` to be valid. Presumably it would increment `c` twice, and evaluate to the value in between the old and new values. This imagined language would be "annoying" in the sense that it's only subtly different from C++, which would tend to be confusing.

`++c++` is also valid in C++ if `c` is an instance of a user-defined type that overloads both increment operators. The reason is that an rvalue of user-defined type *is* an object (a "temporary object"), and can be modified. But as soon as the expression has been evaluated, the temporary is destroyed and the modification is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to Explain this is that the `++` operator only operates on an lvalue. But when you combine them, it's parsed as either `++(c++)` or `(++c)++` -- in either case, the parameter to the operator outside the parentheses is an rvalue (`c`'s value before or after the increment), not an lvalue.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really understand what rvalue and lvalues are, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Luc: An lvalue is pretty much something whose value can be changed.

Comment: lvalues are things you can modify, like variables, array elements, and structure members -- they refer to a storage location (the term "lvalue" refers to the fact that it can be on the left side of an assignment). rvalues are expressions that don't necessarily denote a storage location, they may be the result of an arbitrary expression (the term refers to the fact that they appear on the right side of an assignment). It only makes sense to perform incrementing on the contents of a location, so it has to be an lvalue -- you wouldn't expect `(foo*bar)++` to work, would you?

Comment: See <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)> for more extensive discussion of this.

Comment: There are some non-modifiable lvalues, for example the name of an array or a `const` variable. So to a first approximation, an lvalue is indeed something that can be modified, but "an expression that refers to a storage location" is more precise.